# What shall I do with baby pineapple plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, pineapple

Hey so my plants didn’t get watered for a few weeks as I was away and unable to do it. I have come back and the pineapple on my pineapple plant has fallen down to one side, shrivelled up and gone hard. The leaves under and on top of the pineapple are still green. I’m not really sure what to do with it or if I can revive it. Any help or advice would be very helpful

Comment: Hi. Some photos of the plant would be useful.